# Conditional cumulative sum associated with the date in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, conditional-statements, cumsum

I want to compute cumulative sum within 5 days for each group.

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = ymd( c( "2022-01-02","2022-01-03","2022-01-05","2022-01-07","2022-01-11","2022-01-14","2022-01-17","2022-01-18","2022-01-24","2022-01-27","2022-01-01","2022-01-04","2022-01-04","2022-01-08","2022-01-12","2022-01-14","2022-01-19","2022-01-24","2022-01-25","2022-01-28")),
  group = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
  number = c(10,30,20,50,30,50,40,50,30,50,55,10,30,20,50,30,40,30,40,30))
```

A small sample of my data frame is below including what the cumulative sum column should return.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
date       group number cumsum(s)
2022-01-02 A     10     10
2022-01-03 A     30     40
2022-01-05 A     20     60
2022-01-07 A     50     110
2022-01-11 A     30     80
2022-01-14 A     50     80
2022-01-17 A     40     90
2022-01-18 A     50     140
2022-01-24 A     30     30
2022-01-27 A     50     80
2022-01-01 B     55     55
2022-01-04 B     10     65
2022-01-04 B     30     95
2022-01-08 B     20     60
2022-01-12 B     50     70
2022-01-14 B     30     80
2022-01-19 B     40     70
2022-01-24 B     30     70
2022-01-25 B     40     70
2022-01-28 B     30     100
```

I tried to use map() and cumsum() but failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join the data on itself, using a non-equi join in `data.table`, and using `.EACHI` to estimate the cumulative sum

```
library(data.table)

df = setDT(df)[, d:=date-5][]

cbind(
  df[df,on=.(group,date<=date, date>=d), .(result = sum(number)), .EACHI][, .(group,date,result)],
  df[, .(number)]
)
```

Output:

```
    group       date result number
 1:     A 2022-01-02     10     10
 2:     A 2022-01-03     40     30
 3:     A 2022-01-05     60     20
 4:     A 2022-01-07    110     50
 5:     A 2022-01-11     80     30
 6:     A 2022-01-14     80     50
 7:     A 2022-01-17     90     40
 8:     A 2022-01-18    140     50
 9:     A 2022-01-24     30     30
10:     A 2022-01-27     80     50
11:     B 2022-01-01     55     55
12:     B 2022-01-04     95     10
13:     B 2022-01-04     95     30
14:     B 2022-01-08     60     20
15:     B 2022-01-12     70     50
16:     B 2022-01-14     80     30
17:     B 2022-01-19     70     40
18:     B 2022-01-24     70     30
19:     B 2022-01-25     70     40
20:     B 2022-01-28    100     30
```

### Update - alternative approach

Let's say we want to do this for multiple shift values.  Another way to do this is to get the overall cumulative sum for each group, over the entire set of days (including days not represented), and use shift.

1. Load data.table and set the table using `setDT()

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

2. Expand each group to min and max date, and get overall cumulative sum, per group

```
df = df[df[, data.table(date=seq(min(date), max(date),1)), group], on=.(group,date)][
  ,cs:=cumsum(fifelse(is.na(number),0,number)),group]
```

3. Now, create a helper function, f, that takes a shift value (say 5, or 10) and returns the cumulative sum for that shift

```
f <- function(s,cs) {
  r = cs-shift(cs,s+1)
  r[is.na(r)] <- cs[is.na(r)]
  r
}
```

4. Set a vector of your desired shifts, and apply the function to each of those shift values

```
s = c(3,5,7,10)
df[, (paste0("c",s)):=lapply(s, f,cs=cs),group][!is.na(number)]
```

Output:

```
          date  group number    cs    c3    c5    c7   c10
        <Date> <char>  <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
 1: 2022-01-02      A     10    10    10    10    10    10
 2: 2022-01-03      A     30    40    40    40    40    40
 3: 2022-01-05      A     20    60    60    60    60    60
 4: 2022-01-07      A     50   110    70   110   110   110
 5: 2022-01-11      A     30   140    30    80   100   140
 6: 2022-01-14      A     50   190    80    80   130   150
 7: 2022-01-17      A     40   230    90    90   120   170
 8: 2022-01-18      A     50   280    90   140   170   170
 9: 2022-01-24      A     30   310    30    30   120   170
10: 2022-01-27      A     50   360    80    80    80   170
11: 2022-01-01      B     55    55    55    55    55    55
12: 2022-01-04      B     10    65    65    65    65    65
13: 2022-01-04      B     30    95    40    95    95    95
14: 2022-01-08      B     20   115    20    60    60   115
15: 2022-01-12      B     50   165    50    70    70   110
16: 2022-01-14      B     30   195    80    80   100   130
17: 2022-01-19      B     40   235    40    70   120   120
18: 2022-01-24      B     30   265    30    70    70   100
19: 2022-01-25      B     40   305    70    70   110   110
20: 2022-01-28      B     30   335    70   100   100   140
          date  group number    cs    c3    c5    c7   c10
```

Comment: In fact, my data frame has 1.6 million observations, and I'm trying to get one or more cumulative sums. Is there a better way than the one below?  
*******
`df = setDT(df)[, d:=date-5][]

cbind(
  df[df,on=.(group,date<=date, date>=d), .(result = sum(number)), .EACHI][, .(group,date,result)],
  df[, .(number)]
)`  
*******
`df = setDT(df)[, d:=date-10][]

cbind(
  df[df,on=.(group,date<=date, date>=d), .(result2 = sum(number)), .EACHI][, .(group,date,result2)],
  df[, .(number,result)]
)`

Comment: sure, see my edit for an alternative that takes a completely different approach

Answer (score 6):

This gives the expected output:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = sapply(date, \(x) sum(number[date >= (x - 5) & date <= x])))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>    date       group number cumsum
#>    <date>     <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 2022-01-02 A         10     10
#>  2 2022-01-03 A         30     40
#>  3 2022-01-05 A         20     60
#>  4 2022-01-07 A         50    110
#>  5 2022-01-11 A         30     80
#>  6 2022-01-14 A         50     80
#>  7 2022-01-17 A         40     90
#>  8 2022-01-18 A         50    140
#>  9 2022-01-24 A         30     30
#> 10 2022-01-27 A         50     80
#> 11 2022-01-01 B         55     55
#> 12 2022-01-04 B         10     95
#> 13 2022-01-04 B         30     95
#> 14 2022-01-08 B         20     60
#> 15 2022-01-12 B         50     70
#> 16 2022-01-14 B         30     80
#> 17 2022-01-19 B         40     70
#> 18 2022-01-24 B         30     70
#> 19 2022-01-25 B         40     70
#> 20 2022-01-28 B         30    100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your help and effort ! 
I'll try this one, too.

Answer (score 3):

We could get the `diff`erence of `date` to create a logical vector, get the cumulative sum and use that in grouping and get the `cumsum` of 'number'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(difgrp =cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(date) >=4))) %>% 
   group_by(diffgrp, .add = TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(s = cumsum(number)) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-diffgrp)
```